# How to see logs from the back-end of /sys

Tags: linux, filesystems, operating-systems, linux-kernel, error-logging

I am trying to modify something in `/sys`. My command is failing.

e.g. `echo 63 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:62:00.0/sriov_numvfs` -> `bash: echo: write error: Cannot allocate memory`

e.g. `echo three > /sys/devices/system/node/node1/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages` -> `bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

How can I debug these failures? Is there a general method to find the logs for whatever is on the other side of these virtual files? Ideally I want to find the process or source code for whatever is generating the error message.

Comment: The "_other side_" of these nodes is handled by the kernel - many of the nodes in `sysfs` are only intended to provide information (i.e: are read only), and many others can only be written to while the system is in a certain state (e.g: not configured).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is [the Linux kernel.](https://www.kernel.org/) Its source code can be found on various Git repositories.

Log messages generated by the kernel would show up in `dmesg` (with the exception of ["debug"-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936199/why-is-pr-debug-of-the-linux-kernel-not-giving-any-output) messages which need to be enabled first).

Sysfs attributes are defined and handled by the device drivers, but it's usually easier to just `git grep` (or use Elixir online search) for the specific filename that causes problems and keep digging from there. Look for a pair of "store"/"show" functions, which accept your writes and provide data for your reads.

- Writes to `sriov_numvfs` are handled by `sriov_numvfs_store()` in [drivers/pci/pci-sysfs.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/pci-sysfs.c#L578). The error messages it prints (using pci_info or pci_err) go to dmesg.
- The part that handles writes to `nr_hugepages` (both the global sysctl and per-node attributes) appears to be in [mm/hugetlb.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/hugetlb.c#L2401) – look for function `__nr_hugepages_store_common()`. Unfortunately the code doesn't actually generate log messages in the first place.